# Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, variance

Suppose $\mathbf{X}=[X_1,\ldots,X_K ]^\top$ is a random vector with mean $\theta\mathbf{1}$ and covariance $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. If $\mathbf{w} = [w_1,…,w_K ]^\top$ is a vector which minimizes the objective function
$$ \operatorname E\big[ (\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{X} - \theta)^2 \big] $$
subject to
$$ \mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{1} = 1 $$
$$ \mathbf{w} \ge \mathbf{0} $$
then it's my understanding that the solution is given by
$$ \mathbf{w}_0 = \frac{\mathbf{Σ}^{-1} \mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}^\top \mathbf{Σ}^{-1} \mathbf{1}} $$
I'm able to use the Lagrange multiplier method to show that this vector is a critical point. However, I'm not sure how to do a sort of second-derivative check using a similar approach. So, I have two questions:

1. Can I extend the Lagrange method to do this second-derivative check?
2. Is there a simpler way to show that this vector is in fact a minimum?

Comment: Second-derivative tests show at most a _local_, rather than global, maximum, and second-derivative tests are not the only way to show that a critical point is a maximum.

Comment: Your two constraints $\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{1} = 1$ and $\mathbf{w} \ge 0$ say that $\mathbf w$ lies in a certain topologically compact space. A continuous function on a compact space has a global maximum point within that space. If the function is smooth enough (I'm not sure whether "everywhere differentiable" is entirely enough in this case) so that a global maximum can occur only at points where Lagrange multipliers exist, then finding one such point will be enough, if you explain what this present comment says. A possible complication in this instance$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$may be that the space has "edges", so maybe you need to say something about those. $\qquad$

Comment: I wrote "then finding one such point will be enough". I should have said it will be enough if you show that it is the _only_ one. $\qquad$

Comment: (I'm presuming it's assumed that $\Sigma$ is nonsingular.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to minimize $\operatorname{var}(\mathbf w^\top \mathbf X) = \mathbf w^\top\Sigma\mathbf w$ subject to a stated constraint on the sum of the scalar entries in $\mathbf w,$ that sum being positive. The existence of at least one local minimum point follows from the fact that it was given that the entries in $\mathbf w$ are all nonnegative and they add up to $1,$ so that we're minimizing a continuous function on a topologically compact space.

The global minimum cannot occur at more than one point for the following reason. Suppose $\mathbf w_1,\,\mathbf w_2$ are two distinct global minimum points. Then $\mathbf w_1^\top \Sigma\mathbf w_1 = \mathbf w_2^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_2$ is the global minimum value. Let $a\mathbf w_1+(1-a)\mathbf w_2$ be a weighted average of the two, so that $0<a<1.$ Then
\begin{align}
& (a\mathbf w_1+(1-a)\mathbf w_2)^\top\Sigma(a\mathbf w_1+(1-a)\mathbf w_2) \\[10pt]
= {} & a^2\mathbf w_1^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_1 + (1-a)^2 \mathbf w_2^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_2 + 2a\mathbf w_1^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_2 \\
& \qquad \text{(Here we used the fact that $\Sigma^\top=\Sigma$.)} \\[10pt]
= {} & a^2\mathbf w_1^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_1 + (1-a)^2 \mathbf w_1^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_1 + 2a\mathbf w_1^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_2 \\
& \qquad \text{(since the same minimum value is attained at both points)} \\[10pt]
< {} & a^2\mathbf w_1^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_1 + (1-a)^2 \mathbf w_1^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_1 + 2a\mathbf w_1^\top\Sigma\mathbf w_1 \\
& \qquad \text{(Cauchy–Schwarz)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \left(\mathbb w_1^\top\Sigma \mathbb w_1\right)\left( a^2 + 2a(1-a) + (1-a)^2 \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \mathbb w_1^\top\Sigma \mathbb w_1.
\end{align}
This there would be an even smaller value than the smallest value.

(This instance of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality is strict since the two vectors cannot be scalar multiples of each other.)

If the functions involved are well-behaved enough to show that a local minimum can occur only where Lagrange multipliers exist, then (since a global minimum is a local minimum) you're done.

Comment: What a simple proof. This is much easier to digest than Lagrangian duality which was the road I thought I needed to head down. Thank you!